Intermittent HTTP Connection Issues Between GKE and Heroku: Excessive Port Allocation in Cloud NAT
I am encountering an issue with intermittent HTTP connection disruptions in our system. While I understand the cause of the disconnections, I am unsure why this cause arises.
Background:

Our service is deployed in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).
We use Cloud NAT above GKE to enable requests to the public internet.
The service is a Go application.

The Problem:
During GET requests to a service deployed on Heroku (which I suspect to be the root cause, detailed below), Cloud NAT unexpectedly allocates a large number of ports. Once the number of allocated ports reaches 1024, every outgoing connection from the pod to this service is cut off by Cloud NAT (typical error in the go service: read tcp 10.10.0.50:50450->12.123.123.123:443: read: connection reset by peer)
Why do I think Heroku is the issue?
In our dev cluster, I deployed a slightly modified version of our app with an endpoint that accepts the following example parameters:
{
    "targetURL": "https://httpbin.org/delay/7",
    "idleConnections": 2,
    "numGoroutines": 10,
    "maxRequestsPerSecond": 100,
    "totalRequests": 3000,
    "disableKeepAlives": false,
    "maxConnsPerHost": 10000
}

This endpoint sends totalRequests to targetURL at the rate of maxRequestsPerSecond. I added tuning options for the client and transport settings of these requests to check their impact.
How did I validate the tests?
I sent thousands, even hundreds of thousands, of GET requests from the pod to various test APIs (e.g., httpbin.org, httpbin.dev) and popular websites (e.g., google.com, github.com) and some other random websites. These tests showed almost 100% successful requests without significant port allocation issues in Cloud NAT. High RPS was achievable even with low idle/max connections and a limited number of goroutines.
However, when requesting a service deployed on Heroku (for example our downstream service in production and dev, review apps in our Heroku environment, and other Heroku-deployed services), connections were starting to drop after a several seconds. Monitoring Cloud NAT during these requests always showed a dramatic increase in allocated ports.
Initially, I suspected the port allocation strategy (Cloud NAT documentation states it's dependent on the number of IPs a domain resolves to). However, testing with services resolving to a single IP, or multiple IPs (up to 4), showed similar port allocation behavior (our downstream service resolves to 2 IPs).
While this issue might seem minor, it significantly impacts our goal of achieving high throughput from GKE to our Heroku service (e.g., sending 2000 requests at 20 requests per second triggers the problem, which is relatively low).
Focus:
My aim is to achieve the highest possible throughput for sending requests from GKE to our Heroku service.
I am uncertain if Heroku is the direct cause, but it's a strong suspicion (this behaviour was noticed whenever I was requesting a service deployed within Heroku).
Notably, Heroku application logs do not show errors or evidence of the dropped requests (which makes sense, as this happens within the Cloud NAT layer). For instance, out of 1000 requests to Heroku, 800 succeed, but 200 have connection reset errors - logs only for the 800 successful ones were available on the Heroku service side.
I have reviewed Heroku's networking documentation but found no relevant errors (e.g., Backlog Too Deep) logged in our downstream Heroku app.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with Cloud NAT and Heroku? Any insights into why Cloud NAT might allocate so many ports when interacting with Heroku services, and potential solutions to this problem, would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

I do not think Cloud NAT is the issue here. You will not see connection reset if NAT was the issue, you'll only see connections timed out.
You can verify this by checking your monitoring metrics for the Cloud NAT. Specifically, dropped sent packets. It'll show drops if the NAT was the bottleneck.

Yes, metrics show a lot of dropped packets during these requests. If the scale is not large, independent endpoint mapping errors start appearing. However, if the requests per second (RPS) are high, then out-of-resources errors skyrocket

You can try a couple of things here. 1) Turn off endpoint independent mapping in your gateway unless you specifically need it. 2) If you still see drops with out of resources, increase min ports per vm. 3) You can try dynamic port allocation if you do not need endpoint independent mapping.
